# Const Correctness for wrapped functions

Tags: c++

I have a question regarding design of const correctness for functions. To illustrate my problem I have made a little abstract example:

```
class wrapper
{
public:
    void func1(args) const
    {
        /*do const compliant stuff*/
        this->wrappedObject.func1(otherArgs);   //declared as const
        this->writeToLogbook();
    };

private:
    void writeToLogbook() const
    {
        this->simpleLog = "text";
    };

    mutable std::string simpleLog{};
    Type wrappedObject;
};
```

Although this works, I end up with an obviously non-const function (**write**ToLogbook() ), which needs to be declared as const, so I can use it in an other function declared as const ( func1() const ).

My thoughts to this problem are the following:

1. The wrapper class calls functions of an underlying object and adds some error Handling and io-mapping, but does not change the function of the underlying object itself.
2. Since wrappedObjects.func1() is declared as const, wrapper.func1() shall be declared as const, too in my opinion.
3. writeToLogbook() needs to be defined as const to be callable in wrapper.func1() (Is that always right?)
4. Although writeToLogbook() does not alter the wrapped objects state, I feel uncomfortable of declaring a "write..." function const

Does anyone have a suggestion how to solve this?

Comment: _"Since wrappedObjects.func1() is declared as const, wrapper.func1() shall be declared as const, too in my opinion."_ extremely no. You are doing something that isn't const so don't pretend it is.

Comment: What would a void const function do? The only thing it can do is change state.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Isnt the code you posted already a solution?

Comment: You could solve this with an extra level of indirection.  Imagine `wrapper` has a `Logbook* logger;` member, then `void writeToLogbook() const { logger->Write("text"); }`.

Comment: @PasserBy: In most cases I would agree with you, but in this case, "wrapper" does only something like a "command forwarding". I would appreciate to have the constness forwarded, too.

Comment: @Rotem: In this specific case, the "real" func1 is something like a complex getter. But since I am working with hardware, I need to check, if my sensor is attached, ready to communicate etc. before I can get the value, and I want to log info in case of error. The "void" is only for this simple example.

Comment: @Spinoza But it's clearly not just forwarding. There's state in the wrapper. You're mutating that state. This would be a hack to get around problems, but not something you would want generally.